# Remove undefiend value from drop down list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> Blockquote

while selecting material column first column is showing undefined,so what i need to remove undefined from drop down list,what kind of changes required in html/json data to work this proper.

> Blockquote

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.type = {
 "ceramicAndVetrified": { 
 "flooringWork": {
   "typeOfWork":"Flooring Work",
   "ceramicTile": {
    "activity": "Ceramic Tile",
    "unitOfWork": "sqm",
    "coeffecient": {
     "ceramicTile": "",
     
    },
    "material": "Ceramic floor tile",
    "tileSizes": [{
     "tileDimension": "300X300",
     
    }, {
     "tileDimension": "600X600",
     
    }]
   },
   "vitrifiedTile": {
    "activity": "Vitrified Tile",
    "unitOfWork": "sqm",
    "coeffecient": {
     
    },
    "material": "Vitrified floor tile",
    "tileSizes": [{
     "tileDimension": "600X600",
     
    }, {
     "tileDimension": "800X800",
     
    }, {
     "tileDimension": "1200X600",
     
    }]
   }
  },
  "wallTilingWork": {
   "typeOfWork":"Wall Tiling Work",
   "ceramicTile": {
    "activity": "Ceramic Tile",
    "unitOfWork": "sqm",
    "coeffecient": {
     "ceramicTile": "",
     
    },
    "material": "Ceramic wall tile",
    "tileSizes": [{
     "tileDimension": "300X300",
     
    }, {
     "tileDimension": "450X450",
     
    }, {
     "tileDimension": "300X450",
     
    }]
   },
   "vitrifiedTile": {
    "activity": "Vitrified Tile",
    "unitOfWork": "sqm",
    "coeffecient": {
     
    },
    "material": "Vitrified wall tile",
    "tileSizes": [{
     "tileDimension": "450X450",
     
    }, {
     "tileDimension": "300X450",
     
    }]
   }
  }
 },
 "images": {
  "calculatorHeaderImage": "http://www.msupply.com/media/catalog/product/0/0/00201000404.jpg",
  "imageURLs": ["http://www.msupply.com/media/catalog/product/0/0/00201000404.jpg", "http://www.msupply.com/media/catalog/product/0/0/00201000404.jpg"]
 }
}

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
     <body>
          <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
                <script src="newscript.js"></script>
<div class = "col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 center-output " ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl" >
     
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <h6>type </h6>
                              <select class="form-control" id="category"  ng-model="selectedcategory" ng-options="y.typeOfWork for (x, y) in type.ceramicAndVetrified" ng-change="GetSelectedCategary()">

                              </select>
                              <span class="arrow"></span>
                         </div> 
                    </div> 
                  
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <h6> Material </h6>
                              <select class="form-control" id="sel2" ng-disabled="!selectedcategory" ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="y.activity for (x, y) in selectedcategory" ng-change="GetSelectedType()">
                              </select>
                             
                         </div> 
                    </div> 
                    
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <h6>Size: </h6>
                              <select class="form-control" id="sel3"  ng-disabled="!selectedtype" ng-model="selectedsize" ng-options="y.tileDimension for (x, y) in selectedtype.tileSizes">
                              
                              </select>
                              <span class="arrow"></span>
                         </div> 
                    </div> 
               </div>
          </div>
</html> 
</body>
```

Comment: your json structure is not consistent.Please make it consistent

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, that is the only problem how to make json consistent because i need to display activity column only not a key, for UI display

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the `typeOfWork.activity` is `undefined`

```
"flooringWork": {
            "typeOfWork":"Flooring Work",
```

You should consider changing your data structure, or creating a filter which check for `[Object].activity`.

---

If you can change the data, you should consider something like this;

```
    {
  "flooringWork":
  {
    "typeOfWork": "Flooring Work",
    "activities": [
      {
        "ceramicTile": {
          "activity": "Ceramic Tile",
          "unitOfWork": "sqm",
          "coeffecient": {
            "ceramicTile": "",

          },
          "material": "Ceramic floor tile",
          "tileSizes": [
            {
              "tileDimension": "300X300",

            }, {
              "tileDimension": "600X600",

            }
          ]
        },
        "vitrifiedTile": {
          "activity": "Vitrified Tile",
          "unitOfWork": "sqm",
          "coeffecient": {},
          "material": "Vitrified floor tile",
          "tileSizes": [
            {
              "tileDimension": "600X600",

            }, {
              "tileDimension": "800X800",

            }, {
              "tileDimension": "1200X600",

            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can update your select to this;

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel2" ng-disabled="!selectedcategory" ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="y.activity for (x, y) in selectedcategory.activities" ng-change="GetSelectedType()">
                              </select>
```

Comment: if i am adding "flooringWork": {
            "typeOfWork":"Flooring Work",
            "activities": [
             { }
            ]

Comment: then its not displaying anything in secound column

Comment: As said, you must update the HTML too, of course putting your activites inside the activities array

Comment: yes its fine but at a time only one activity is dispalying because we can't give both activity in same variable."typeOfWork" : "Flooring Work",
                    "activities" : [
                         {
                              "activity" : "Ceramic Tile",
                               "activity" : "Vitrified Tile"
                              
                         }],